# Dash: Dynamic Pattern Matching

Tags: python, pattern-matching, plotly-dash

I need a little help with understanding pattern matching.  I'm trying to generate input boxes (or sliders, doesn't matter) based on the number of categorical selections from a drop-down menu.  I can get some of the code working, but I can't seem to make use of the values.

Issue 1: when I select the objects from the menu, the input boxes don't appear

Issue 2: the output doesn't seem to be working properly

Issue 3: I don't know how to save and use the values entered in each of the boxes

I'm expecting to produce an array like [1, 3, 5, 9] from the values entered into each input box that I can use for subsequent calculations or share to another callback.

Thanks in advance for your help!

```
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output, State, MATCH, ALL

app = Dash(__name__, suppress_callback_exceptions=True)

cols = ['apple', 'orange', 'lemon', 'pear']
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Dropdown(id='add-filter', multi=True, options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in cols]),
    html.Div(id='dropdown-container', children=[]),
    html.Div(id='dropdown-container-output')
])

@app.callback(
    Output('dropdown-container', 'children'),
    Input('add-filter', 'value'),
    State('dropdown-container', 'children'))
def display_inputs(values, children):
    n = len(values)
    new_inputs = [dcc.Input(type='number', id={'type':'filter-dropdown', 'index':i})
        for i in range(n)
        ]
    children.append(new_inputs)
    return children

@app.callback(
    Output('dropdown-container-output', 'children'),
    Input({'type': 'filter-dropdown', 'index': ALL}, 'value')
)
def display_output(values):
    return html.Div([
        html.Div('Dropdown {} = {}'.format(i + 1, value))
        for (i, value) in enumerate(values)
    ])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output, State, MATCH, ALL

app = Dash(__name__, suppress_callback_exceptions=True)

cols = ['apple', 'orange', 'lemon', 'pear']
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Dropdown(id='add-filter', multi=True, options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in cols]),
    html.Div(id='dropdown-container', children=[]),
    html.Div(id='dropdown-container-output')
])

@app.callback(
    Output('dropdown-container', 'children'),
    Input('add-filter', 'value'),
    State('dropdown-container', 'children'))
def display_inputs(values, children):
    n = len(values)
    print(values)
    return [dcc.Input(type='number', id={'type':'filter-dropdown', 'index':i})
    #return [dcc.Slider(0,5,1, id={'type':'filter-dropdown', 'index':i})
        for i in range(n)
        ]

@app.callback(
    Output('dropdown-container-output', 'children'),
    Input({'type': 'filter-dropdown', 'index': ALL}, 'value')
)
def display_output(values):
    a = []
    for (i, value) in enumerate(values):
        a.append(value)
    print(a)
    return html.Div([
        html.Div('Dropdown {} = {}'.format(i + 1, value))
        for (i, value) in enumerate(values)
    ])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```